# Defining an inner product by means of a multilinear functional

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V$ be a complex vector space and an anti-linear involution $J:V \rightarrow V$ (this means that $J^2 = I$  and if $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and $x, y \in V$ we have $J(\lambda x + y) = \overline{\lambda} J(x)+J(y)$). Fix $N$ a natural number and consider a multilinear functional $\omega:V^{2N}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that:

1. $\omega(x_1,...,x_{2N}) = \omega(x_2, ..., x_{2N},x_1)$, for every $x_1,x_2,...,x_{2N} \in V$
2. The matrix $A$ whose matrix elements $A_{ij}$ defined by 
   $A_{ij} = \omega(Jx_{i1},..., Jx_{iN}, x_{j1},..., x_{jN})$ is positive semi-definite for every $x_{kl} \in V$, $k=1,..., n$ and $l=1,...,N$, where $n$ can be any natural number.

I saw this on a paper that I'm currently reading and the author claims that the condition 2 implies that the following:
$$\langle x, y \rangle = \omega(x_1,..., x_N, Jy_N,... Jy_1)$$

defines an inner product in $V^N$. I'm not sure about this because this is not linear in the first coordinate. Did I get this wrong?

Comment: I suppose $M$ should actually be $N$?

Comment: You're right, I'll edit!

Comment: And I suppose $n$ should also actually be $N$?

Comment: In the paper, the author wrote just like that!

Comment: Well, what is $n$ then?

Comment: It can be any natural number, I put that information in the question now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62263/discussion-between-affonso-and-fimpellizieri).